# Bootstrap-Vue - Select Component

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I need to create a component with 2 lists that can I navigate on list 1 and add elements to list 2.
Like this image:
[image]

Is there a component like that?
I Checked on Form Select but didn't find.

Thanks!

Comment: could you show some tried work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own. Add a CSS style ":selected" and when a button is pressed then add the selected one with Vue.

Comment: Yes I know. I was already wondering how to create one. I just want to check if already exists one similar on bootstrap-vue.
To create I can use 2 `<b-list-group-item>` for list 1 and list 2? How can I check what element is selected? Search for active class? Can I add a scroll bar on `<b-list-group-item>`? Thanks for the help!